# How to add right mouse button event to cell in table layout?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have added a mouse event controller to my table layout but it is not working, below is the work so far I have done

```
private void tablelayout_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Add Device")); 
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Delete Device"));
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Fire"));
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Fault"));
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Suppress"));

         }

 }
```

This is the form and table layout I have designed

[image: http://i47.tinypic.com/29mnfhj.jpg]

http://tinypic.com/r/29mnfhj/6

Comment: what is problem in this?

Comment: You created a context menu, but then you didn't show it. It's working as intended.

Comment: If you want to show a context menu on right click, why don't you simply use the `ContextMenu` property of the control? You can do all of that on the designer, which is far more convenient.

Comment: @Alvin Wong when i click right mouse button on a table cell, it is not showing any context menu.

Comment: @Freelancer when i click right mouse button on a table cell, it is not showing any context menu

Comment: have these answers solved your problem ? if yes maybe It's better to take a moment and choose the answer for your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you don't show the `ContextMenu` at all

```
    private void tableLayout_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Add Device"));
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Delete Device"));
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Fire"));
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Fault"));
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Suppress"));
            //add this line to the event handler
            m.Show((Control)(sender), e.Location);
        }
    }
```

and for your question about adding event handlers for this context menu for every single one of menu items you need to define an event handler like this :

```
m.MenuItems[0].Click += MenuItemClick;
```

and for the event :

```
void MenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code 
}
```

so far we have defined click event handler for `MenuItem("Add Device")` repeat these steps for other MenuItems as well as this one

Comment: i added this code to call the event handler                                                                       `private void AssignClickEvent()
        {
            foreach (Control c in tableLayout.Controls.OfType<Button>())
            {
                
                c.Click += new EventHandler(tablelayout_MouseClick);
            }
        }  `                                                                                                                            but it is giving error like no overload for tablelayout_Mouseclick

Comment: use this one instead : `private void AssignClickEvent() { foreach (Control c in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Button>()) { c.MouseClick += tableLayoutPanel1_MouseClick; }}`

Comment: remember to use `c.MouseClick` instead of `c.Click`

Comment: one more thing i have used `tableLayoutPanel1` instead of `tableLayout` as the name in my comments so please change them yourself

Comment: how to add click event to above context menu items

Answer (score 3):

Remember to call

```
m.Show(tablelayout, e.Location);
```